# How to customize AJAX form in Wordpress

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress, curl

First I do not want to modify any main or original scripts in Wordpress template.

Can I directly create the form (not require database) in Wordpress page? Or I shall create plugins in order to attach it onto specific Wordpress page?

I have tested outside Wordpress and successfully to using AJAX Call. I've tried to insert the scripts in Page Editor's Text mode, but it's not working after update the page.

General workflow is following:

1. [form.html] file has a form for user selects and submit to retrieve result from server without refresh the page.
2. AJAX in (either external call.js JavaScript file) the HTML file will sending the data to [proccess.php] file.
3. The PHP file will compile all the data and do input validation.
4. PHP file will sending data to 3rd party service thru cURL and retrieve result in JSON format.
5. PHP send back data to HTML file.
6. HTML file convert and showing data on the page.

HTML (form.html)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".new-loan").click(function(){
        $(".newloanTab1").show();
        $(".refinanceTab1").hide();
        $(".refinanceTab2").hide();
    });

    $(".refinance").click(function(){
        $(".refinanceTab2").show();
        $(".newloanTab1").hide();
    });

    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($('input[value="refinance"]').is(":checked") && $('input[value="commercial"]').is(":checked")) {
          $(".refinanceTab1").show();
        } else {
          $(".refinanceTab1").hide();
        }
    });

});
</script> 

<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<form id="loanform">
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="mainForm">
      <div id="loan-type-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="loan_type">Loan Type <strong>*</strong></label>
        <input type="radio" name="loan_type" value="new_loan" class="new-loan" />New Loan
        <input type="radio" name="loan_type" value="refinance" class="refinance" />Refinance

      </div>

    </div>    
    <div style="display: none;" id="refinance" class="refinanceTab1">
        <div id="individual-or-company-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="individual_or_company">Individual / Company <strong>*</strong></label>
        <input type="radio" name="individual_or_company" value="individual" class="refinance-individual" checked="checked" />Individual
        <input type="radio" name="individual_or_company" value="company" class="refinance-company" />Company

        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="refinance" class="refinanceTab2">
        <div id="current-financer-ddl-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="current_financer_ddl">Current Financer <strong>*</strong></label>
        <select name="current_financer_ddl" class="current-financer-ddl">
            <option value="financer1">Financer 1</option>
            <option value="financer2">Financer 2</option>
        </select>

        </div>
        <div id="existing-loan-amount-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="existing_loan_amount">Existing Loan Amount<strong>*</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="existing_loan_amount" class="existing-loan-amount">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="new-loan" class="newloanTab1">
        <div id="property-purchase-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="property_purchase">Property Purchase <strong>*</strong></label>
        <input type="radio" name="property_purchase" value="yes" class="property-purchase" checked="checked" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="property_purchase" value="no" class="property-purchase" />No

        </div>
        <div id="construction-status-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="construction_status">Construction Status <strong>*</strong></label>
        <input type="radio" name="construction_status" value="completed" class="construction-status" checked="checked" />Completed
        <input type="radio" name="construction_status" value="under-construction" class="construction-status" />Under-Construction

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainForm2">
      <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email <strong>*</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="email">

      </div>
      <div id="contact-name-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="contact_name">Contact Name <strong>*</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="contact-name">

      </div>
      <div id="phone-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone <strong>*</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="phone">

      </div>

    </div>    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
    </form>
    <script src="call.js"></script>
</div>
```

JavaScript (call.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $('.help-block').remove();

        var formData = {
            'loan_type'                 : $('input[name=loan_type]:checked').val(),
            'individual_or_company'     : $('input[name=individual_or_company]:checked').val(),
            'current_financer_ddl'      : $('select[name=current_financer_ddl] option:selected').val(), 
            'existing_loan_amount'      : $('input[name=existing_loan_amount]').val(),
            'property_purchase'         : $('input[name=property_purchase]:checked').val(),
            'construction_status'       : $('input[name=construction_status]:checked').val(),
            'email'                     : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'contact_name'              : $('input[name=contact_name]').val(),
            'phone'                     : $('input[name=phone]').val(),
            };
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'ajaxtest.php',
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'json',
            encode      : true,
            success: function(data) {
                        if ( data.success == false ){
                            if (data.errors.loan_type) {
                                $('#loan-type-group').addClass('has-error');
                                $('#loan-type-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.loan_type + '</div>');
                            }
                            if (data.errors.individual_or_company) {
                                $('#individual-or-company-group').addClass('has-error');
                                $('#individual-or-company-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.individual_or_company + '</div>');
                            }
                            if (data.errors.current_financer_ddl) {
                                $('#current-financer-ddl-group').addClass('has-error');
                                $('#current-financer-ddl-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.current_financer_ddl + '</div>');
                            }
                            if (data.errors.existing_loan_amount) {
                                $('#existing-loan-amount-group').addClass('has-error');
                                $('#existing-loan-amount-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.existing_loan_amount + '</div>');
                            }
                            if (data.errors.property_purchase) {
                                $('#property-purchase-group').addClass('has-error');
                                $('#property-purchase-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.property_purchase + '</div>');
                            }
                            if (data.errors.construction_status) {
                                $('#construction-status-group').addClass('has-error');
                                $('#construction-status-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.construction_status + '</div>');
                            }
                            if (data.errors.email) {
                                $('#email-group').addClass('has-error');
                                $('#email-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>');
                            }
                            if (data.errors.contact_name) {
                                $('#contact-name-group').addClass('has-error');
                                $('#contact-name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.contact_name + '</div>');
                            }
                            if (data.errors.phone) {
                                $('#phone-group').addClass('has-error');
                                $('#phone-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.phone + '</div>');
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message.success + '</div>');
                            alert('success'); 
                        }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP (process.php)

```
$loan_type = $individual_or_company = $current_financer_ddl = $existing_loan_amount = $property_purchase = $construction_status = $email = $contact_name = $phone = "";

    $errors         = array();
    $data           = array();

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        if(empty($_POST["loan_type"])){
            $errors['loan_type'] = "Loan Type is required";
        }
        else{
            $loan_type = test_input($_POST["loan_type"]);
        }

        if($loan_type=="refinance" && $property_type=="commercial"){
            if(empty($_POST["individual_or_company"])){
                $errors['individual_or_company'] = "Individual / Company is required";
            }
            else{
                $individual_or_company  = test_input($_POST["individual_or_company"]);
            }
        }
        if($loan_type=="refinance"){
            if(empty($_POST["current_financer_ddl"])){
                $errors['current_financer_ddl'] = "Current Financer is required";
            }
            else{
                $current_financer_ddl   = test_input($_POST["current_financer_ddl"]);
            }

            if(empty($_POST["existing_loan_amount"])){
                $errors['existing_loan_amount'] = "Existing Loan Amount is required";
            }
            else{
                $existing_loan_amount   = test_input($_POST["existing_loan_amount"]);
                if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?$/',$existing_loan_amount)){
                    $errors['existing_loan_amount'] = "Only numeric is allowed.";
                }
            }

            $property_purchase = $construction_status = "";
        }

        if($loan_type=="new_loan"){
            if(empty($_POST["property_purchase"])){
                $errors['property_purchase'] = "Property Purchase is required";
            }
            else{
                $property_purchase      = test_input($_POST["property_purchase"]);
            }

            if(empty($_POST["construction_status"])){
                $errors['construction_status'] = "Construction Status is required";
            }
            else{
                $construction_status    = test_input($_POST["construction_status"]);
            }

            $existing_loan_amount = $current_financer_ddl = $individual_or_company = "";
        }

        if(empty($_POST["email"])){
            $errors['email'] = "Email is required";
        }
        else{
            $email                  = test_input($_POST["email"]);
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $errors['email'] = "Invalid email format"; 
            }
        }

        if(empty($_POST["contact_name"])){
            $errors['contact_name'] = "Contact Name is required";
        }
        else{
            $contact_name           = test_input($_POST["contact_name"]);
            if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$contact_name)) {
                $errors['contact_name'] = "Only letters and white space are allowed";
            }
        }

        if(empty($_POST["phone"])){
            $errors['phone'] = "Phone is required";
        }
        else{
            $phone                  = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
            if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $phone)){
                $errors['phone'] = "Only numeric is allowed";
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty($errors)) {
            $data['http_success'] = false;
            $data['errors']  = $errors;
        } else {
            $data['http_success'] = true;
            $data['http_message'] = 'Success!';

            $myUrl = "http://mortgage.redbrick.sg/api/lead/addlead";
            $fields_string = "";
            if(empty($individual_or_company)){
                $individual_or_company = "individual";
            }

            $fields = array(
                    "loan_type"             => $loan_type,          
                    "individual_or_company" => $individual_or_company,
                    "current_financer_ddl"  => $current_financer_ddl,
                    "existing_loan_amount"  => $existing_loan_amount,
                    "property_purchase"     => $property_purchase,
                    "construction_status"   => $construction_status,
                    "email"                 => $email,
                    "contact_name"          => $contact_name,
                    "phone"                 => $phone,
                    "apikey"                => "some key"
                    ); 

            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
                $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
            }
            $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
            $url = $myUrl.'?'.$fields_string;
            $ch = curl_init();                                                                      
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            $api_response = curl_exec($ch);
            $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if ($resultStatus == 200) {
                $data['info'] = $resultStatus;
            } else {
                $data['info'] = 'Request failed - HTTP status code: ' . $resultStatus . '<br/>' .curl_error($ch);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            return $api_response;       
        }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please consider using https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for wordpress specific questions

Comment: For starters, you need to enqueue jquery and bootstrap properly in Wordpress.
You can start with this guide but there are many others: http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/

Comment: @CodeBrauer - I didn't even know that existed until now.

Comment: @Difster many users just know stackoverflow - but on wordpress.stackexchange.com are more wordpress-developers that could answer this question much better

Comment: Yeah, I see that now, I just wasn't aware of that particular one. I can't imagine there are nearly as many users there.

Comment: can you able to add javascript in text editor?